# How to have the Page.IsPostBack option using Ajax JQuery Call?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, caching

How to have the following scenario using Ajax jQuery call?
Is there anyway to bind the `DropDownList` just once during the `PostBack` of the page using `jQuery`?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server" DataSourceID="StateDataSource" DataTextField="State1"
    Width="155px" DataValueField="State1" TabIndex="10">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="StateDataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="State_SelectALL"
    TypeName="PL.BLL.StateController" EnableCaching="true">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

The ScriptManager class provides a property IsInAsyncPostback since 3.5, but as you are doing ajax requests through jquery, I suppose you don't use a ScriptManager.

jQuery actually adds an http-header to the request that you could use server-side to check if the request was ajaxed or not: `"X-Requested-With" = "XMLHttpRequest"`

```
// X-Requested-With header
// For cross-domain requests, seeing as conditions for a preflight are
// akin to a jigsaw puzzle, we simply never set it to be sure.
// (it can always be set on a per-request basis or even using ajaxSetup)
// For same-domain requests, won't change header if already provided.
if ( !s.crossDomain && !headers["X-Requested-With"] ) {
    headers[ "X-Requested-With" ] = "XMLHttpRequest";
}
```

In your code-behind, you could add a property to you page (or your base page - or make an extension method) to check the value:

```
public bool IsAjaxPostback
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
    }
}
```

Good article on the subject: [Detecting Ajax Events on the Server](http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/03/detecting-ajax-events-on-the-server)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(IsPostBack)
   {
     //do stuff on .net postback
   }

   var scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);

   if(scriptManager.IsInAsyncPostBack)
   {
     //do stuff on .net ajax postbacks
   }
}
```